# How to make an empty histogram with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I'm plotting histograms and then stitching them together to make an animated plot. Sometimes my data really is an empty list, but the following code errors:

```
>>> plt.hist([])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2008, in hist
    ret = ax.hist(x, bins, range, normed, weights, cumulative, bottom, histtype, align, orientation, rwidth, log, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes.py", line 7116, in hist
    m, bins = np.histogram(x[i], bins, weights=w[i], **hist_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 202, in histogram
    range = (a.min(), a.max())
ValueError: zero-size array to ufunc.reduce without identity
```

How can I plot an empty histogram?

Comment: could you just test whether the list is empty before calling `plt.hist` in each iteration? Presumably you could remove the previous histogram but leave the axes (easier if you keep the return values from the plot command).

Comment: Since you know the range of `bins`, can you test if `x[i] == []`, then change `x[i]` to contain a value outside of bins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An empty histogram looks the same as an empty plot, and the plot command can take an empty list.

```
if len(data) == 0:
    plt.plot([])
else:
    plt.histogram(data)
```

Comment: I would test `len(data) == 0`, as you probably want `np.array([])` to behave correctly.  also your logic is backwards.

Comment: and remember to accept your own answer when the system will let you.